# does java.util.Random return null

Tags: java, random

`String.format("%04d", new Random().nextInt(10000));`

This gives a four digit number as a string.
Is there any chance that this returns a string "null" by any chance?

string "null" because there is String.format("%04d")

Also, will new Random().nextInt(10000) ever return a null?

I am using this in my application to store in oracle database and found that a string "null" is inserted into the respective column. This is absurd and the only possibility I could see is with
`String.format("%04d", new Random().nextInt(10000));`

Comment: [nextInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) will never return null. The code as you have it posted will work as you expect it to. Maybe you need to show a bit more code. How are you using this statement?

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not return the String "null" for any integer between 0 and 9999:

```
for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){
     String s = String.format("%04d",i);
     if(s.equals("null")) {System.out.println(i);}
}
```

This script does not print any output, which is not surprising because you are formatting the integer as a number string.